# Count the number of rows that have the same value , 24 mil rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

So I have this huge CSV, I made a test script to see the number of rows, and it return about 24 million rows. I want to extract the number of rows that have the same CIK number, and transfer that data in separate CSV.

So the wanted output in the other file would be:

CIK number: number of IP with that CIK number.

I had some ideas, but they weren't efficient enough, so the script was useless, because it took for ages to go through csv. So did someone come a cross a similar problem as I have?

Should I use Pandas for this, any suggestion would be a huge help !

*Example of the CSV:*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a Counter?

```py
import collections, csv

with open("big.csv") as csvfile:
    counter = collections.Counter(row["cik"] for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile))

with open("out.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(("cik", "count"))
    for cik, count in counter.items():
        writer.writerow((cik, count))
```

Memory overhead for this will depend on how many CIKs there are, not how many rows. I don't know how many that is, so I don't know if it'll be an issue.

Comment: This is a good answer. You can also easily write the results to a csv file line-by-line, which should be quick too.

Comment: @brunns Well I already tried with Collection/Counter but had some problems with the code, probably my bad implementation of it. It works, but it takes about 9 minutes to complete for date and cik. I don't know would Pandas do it any quicker?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a pandas user. Maybe it could, but I can't help you with that. I just gave you the best solution I could think of in pure python.

Comment: @HS-nebula, as between us you are most familiar with Pandas, can you answer my earlier question ?

Comment: @Stefan I mean, the way to do it in Pandas is shown in my answer. You could probably read in the file using the `csv` module into a list of lists and then convert that to a dataframe. That might make loading the file faster. I'm not sure the `groupby` will be faster than this answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` to `groupby` the `CIK` column, then use `size()` to get the total number of `CIK` values.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')

ndf = df.groupby('CIK').size()

ndf.to_csv("CIK_number.csv")
```

---

I think I may have misunderstood your desired output. If you want the CIK, IP pairs by the number of times the CIK appears, do

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CIK': ['102', '102', '103', '103', '104'], 'IP':['103.92.134', '103.92.134', '103.92.135', '103.92.136', '105.32.134'], 'C1': [1, 2, 3, 4,5 ], 'C2':[1,0,0,1,0]})

ndf = df.groupby(['CIK','IP'])['CIK'].size().reset_index()

ndf.rename(columns={0: 'count'}, inplace=True)

### returns

    CIK          IP  count
0  102  103.92.134      2
1  103  103.92.135      1
2  103  103.92.136      1
3  104  105.32.134      1
```

To read in a large CSV file in `pandas` do

```
chunks = []
for chunk in pd.read_csv('csv_name.csv', chunksize = 100):
    chunks.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(chunks)
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pandas, but will tryout your solution

Comment: @Stefan I may have misunderstood your desired output. Check if my edit is what you want.

Comment: To read in a large CSV in `pandas` you can use the `chunksize` parameter, then concatenate the smaller dataframes.

Comment: I tried out your past solution @HS-nebula but my script crashed, maybe it can't handle so large file?

Comment: And the question about the output: CIK number: number of IP with that CIK number

Comment: This last suggestion seems good. but how to implement a csv file into that?

Comment: @Stefan see my edit for how to read in the file. To save it, you can do what I suggested in the first part.

Comment: I think this will work, but my fear is it will take ages to complete, and that is something I wanted to avoid

Comment: @Stefan You can of course adjust the chunksize and see which takes the least amount of time. Alternatively, you can read in the file line-by-line as suggested in another answer, convert to a dataframe, and use my suggestions.

Comment: Links like these may help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) @Stefan. However, I do think that using Pandas will be easiest to get the count. You could also only read in the `CIK` and `IP` columns(`pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=['CIK','IP'])`), do the groupby, then save the results. (That way you're not copying and reading the entire dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas, but it is not very efficient:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('my.csv')
```

But the quick and dirty way is to simply stream the file and pull with simple string matching and then write your new file:

```
with open("my.csv") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if "CIK_number" in line : 
            do_something_with(line)
```

Comment: python's csv reader is fine too, but if you are just re-making the exact file maybe you dont need it?  I guess I am assuming you dont want the big object in memory so you want a simple stream.

Comment: You didn't understand my question, I don't want to enter a specific cik. I want for the script to extract how many IP have the same CIK for every IP in the csv, but with the size of the csv, it is problem...

Comment: If you stream each line, the size doesn't matter.  It will not load the full file in memory.